# Microsoft graph API: empty BCC field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Scenario:

1. Jenny and Tom have gmail accounts. Jerry is o365 user
2. Jenny sends email to Tom (in TO: field) and BCC: Jerry.
3. When Jerry gets message from graph api and doesn't see himself in BCC entry, which is empty (in both versions of API - 1 and beta).
4. If Jenny, Jerry and Tom would be in the group and Jenny have sent email to group, it would exactly the same for Jerry. There is no way to distinguish those two cases.

I would expect that when user is in BCC he should see himself there.
I know if sender is O365 user and getsMessage via graph API he will see all BCC users.

Is there any API call that I could use to learn that given user was in BCC of given message?

Here is what Jerry sees:

```
   {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACWhXAbJxpFRb0V3o8I2vIPAACwRstA\"",
        "id": "AAMkAGMyNDE4NGI5LTRlNmItNDUzMy04ZTBlLTgxNjM3MDZhODE5NgBGAAAAAABT6x1NTxG_S7bw4uHJw-_tBwDEbTtXm_E6Rr8LT_x2xj5KAAAAnJfJAACWhXAbJxpFRb0V3o8I2vIPAACwGG_qAAA=",
        "createdDateTime": "2017-11-15T19:50:57Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-15T19:50:57Z",
        "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAACWhXAbJxpFRb0V3o8I2vIPAACwRstA",
        "categories": [],
        "receivedDateTime": "2017-11-15T19:50:57Z",
        "sentDateTime": "2017-11-15T19:50:54Z",
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "internetMessageId": "<CAHF5u5KsOQd43c4dtnx0uTQRor_dt7Y1uy=F3G4i6-c+TdUgug@mail.gmail.com>",
        "subject": "test bcc=",
        "bodyPreview": "test bcc",
        "importance": "normal",
        "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGMyE4NGI5LTRlNmItNDUzMy04ZTBlLTgxNjM3MDZhODE5NgAuAAAAAABT6x1NTxG_S7bw4uHJw-_tAQDEbTtXm_E6Rr8LT_x2xj5KAAAAnJfJAAA=",
        "conversationId": "AAQkAGMyGI5LTRlNmItNDUzMy04ZTBlLTgxNjM3MDZhODE5NgAQAMaAYzrmsyxGq7ZujLh23q0=",
        "conversationIndex": "AQHTXxoBjOuazLEartm6MuHberQ==",
        "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
        "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
        "isRead": false,
        "isDraft": false,
        "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkAGMyNDE4NAACwGG%2BqAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
        "inferenceClassification": "focused",
        "unsubscribeData": [],
        "unsubscribeEnabled": false,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div dir=\"ltr\">test bcc<br>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jenny",
                "address": "jenny1234@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jenny",
                "address": "jenny1234@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Tom",
                    "address": "tom1234@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ccRecipients": [],
        "bccRecipients": [],
        "replyTo": [],
        "mentionsPreview": null,
        "flag": {
            "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any messages that comes from an external source (in this case GMail), there is no `BCC` data available.

This works this way in order to meet the requirements set forth for "Blind Carbon Copy" in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.3).

Comment: Thanks, so effectively there is no way to know if I have received message because I am participant of the group or I was in BCC?

Comment: If you are a participant of the group, your email (or the groups) will show up in  ``To` or `CC` arrays. For `BCC` things work differently. The entire point of this property is that recipients don't know who those recipients were.

Comment: The drama is that when email is sent to group that's no way to distinguish those two cases. You would have to know that you are part of that group. When you use your human eyes you can easily distinguish based on the fact remembering signing up. However purely having just that email and no other knowledge you can't tell :/

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - Could you please tell if Bcc recipients are returned from the `Outlook Rest API`. I ask this because we have come across a scenario to support this, however nowhere (atleast wherver I read) this is mentioned if Bcc recipients are returned or not..The documentation just shows an empty array..And BTW, unlike this case, the mails are being sent from O365 account